# Prove the Galois Group is Isomorphic to $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Prove G=$Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i\sqrt{3}) : \mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $S_3$

I know that the G has 6 automorphims, and $S_3$ has order 3!

then consider polynomial $x^3-2 = (x-2)(x-2\omega)(x-2\omega^2)$

where by De Moivre's Thm $\omega = \cos{\frac{2\pi}{3}} + i\sin{\frac{2\pi}{3}}$

then claim: $\phi$,  $\psi$ are automorphisms to generate a group ismormphic to $S_3$

Define $\phi{(\omega)}$ = $\omega$

Comment: By the way something is wrong with your polynomial factorization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $6$ is already the maximum number of automorphisms possible for a splitting field of a cubic, and any automorphism must permute the roots of that cubic, and conversely the action of the automorphism on those roots completely determine the automorphism, and hence if the splitting field of a cubic has $6$ automorphisms, it must be isomorphic to the whole permutation group on its roots.